# Simplest way to extract date from timestamp

Tags: r, datetime, lubridate

Consider the following timestamp

```
timestamp <- ymd_hms("2011-08-10 14:00:00", tz = "Pacific/Auckland")

> timestamp
[1] "2011-08-10 14:00:00 NZST"
```

What is the simplest way to get the day part `2011-08-10` from it, and making sure this day is a proper date and not a string?

Using `lubridate::day(timestamp)` obviously fails here.

Comment: Just do `as.Date`

Comment: I think you're looking for `lubridate::date`. The difference from `as.Date` is that `date` uses the date as it exists in the assigned time zone instead of converting to UTC first (the default in `as.Date`, though it can take a `tz` parameter).

Comment: `floor_date(timestamp,"day")` yields a POSIXct with the right timezone...

Comment: I think you can also use lubridate and as_date now versus as_datetime 
`mutate(day=as_datetime(timestamp))` and this will work within a pipe

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This would probably be the simplest way:

```
date(timestamp)
```

It will return a date class and not a string.

Answer (score 14):

Use date instead of day

```
lubridate::date(timestamp)
```

Answer (score 4):

There is also `data.table`s `as.IDate()` function now:

```r
timestamp <- "2011-08-10 14:00:00"
data.table::as.IDate(timestamp)
```